# Generate multiple dimension array in CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter

By using the code below in [**CodeIgniter**](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/table.html), we can generate a table as below

```
$this->load->library('table');

$data = array(
             array('11', '12', '13'),
             array('21', '22', '23'),
             array('31', '32', '33'),
             array('41', '42', '43')    
             );

echo $this->table->generate($data);
```

Output:
[image]

I want to ask how can I put this array in for loop likes:

```
for ($x = 0; $x < 5; $x++) {
    for ($y = 0; $y < 4; $y++) {
        $data xxx;
    }
}
```

What is the code to replace in **xxx**?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe:

```
$data= array();
for ($x = 1; $x < 5; $x++) {
    $data[$x]= array(); 
    for ($y = 1; $y < 4; $y++) {
        $data[$x][]= ($x*10)+($y);
    }
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($data);
```

Comment: well done, I misread the question. On my system the third line `$data[$x]= array();` isn't required in order to work.

Comment: Can be omitted. PHP will create the array by assigning an element in `$data[$x][]= ($x*10)+($y);`

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would enumerate the array:

```
foreach ($data as $row) {
    foreach ($row as $cell) {
        echo $cell;
        // Do stuff here!
    }
}
```

If you need the index of each row / column you can use the following variant:

```
foreach ($data as $row_index => $row) {
    foreach ($row as $column_index => $cell) {
        // Stuff!
    }
}
```